# SQL WHILE Loops

Tags: sql, loops, while-loop

I have been working on creating a nested while loop in SQL, but having issues with the while loop. I think the main issue is with my outer loop. Any suggestions?

```
USE HW_DB;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.PythagoreanTriangles') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.PythagoreanTriangles;
GO

CREATE TABLE PythagoreanTriangles
(
    Side1 INT NOT NULL,
    Side2 INT NOT NULL,
    Hypotenuse FLOAT NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @side1 AS INT = 1;
DECLARE @side2 AS INT = 1;
DECLARE @count AS INT = 1;
DECLARE @element  AS INT = 0;

WHILE (@side1 = @count) 
    BEGIN
        WHILE @side2 <= 10 BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.PythagoreanTriangles
                VALUES (@side1, @side2, SQRT((@side2 * @side2) + (@side1 * @side1)));
            UPDATE dbo.PythagoreanTriangles SET Hypotenuse = ROUND(Hypotenuse, 2)

        SET @side2 = @side2 + 1;
        SET @count = @count + 1;
        SET @element = @element + 1;

    IF @element = 10
    BEGIN 
    SET @side1 = @side1 + 1;
    SET @element = 0;

END;
END;
END;
```

Output should look like the following:

1 1 1.41

1 2 2.24

1 3 ...

1 4 ...

1 5 

1 6 

1 7 

1 8 

1 9 

1 10

2 2

2 3

2 4

2 5 

2 6

2 7 

2 8

2 9 

2 10

..........

........ etc

9 9

9 10

10 10

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do by comparing @side1 and @count? The second time your outer 'while' is hit, @count=11 and @side1=2.

Comment: Just thinking further, if the problem is what I think it is, you need to assign @count=@side1 after @side1 is incremented, and change your outer loop to "while (@side1 <= 10)"

Comment: Nested loops seems like an unnecessary complication in this case.  Why not a single loop from 1 to 10?  Better yet, read @GarethD's answer.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a single insert, and where possible I would always advise avoiding loops/cursors.

```
WITH Numbers AS
(   SELECT  TOP 10 Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id)
    FROM    sys.all_objects
)
INSERT dbo.PythagoreanTriangles (Side1, Side2, Hypotenuse)
SELECT  Side1 = a.Number, 
        Side2 = b.Number,
        Hypotenuse = ROUND(SQRT(POWER(a.Number, 2) + POWER(b.Number, 2)), 2)
FROM    Numbers a
        CROSS JOIN Numbers b;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f84e40/1)**

---

Although to actually answer your question, your loop exits after one iteration because you have this condition:

```
WHILE (@side1 = @count)
```

After the first iteration of @side2 1 - 10, you do `SET @side1 = @side1 + 1;`. Since `@Count = 1`, and `@Side1` is now 2, your WHILE predicate is no longer true, so the outer loop exits. Although I don't advocate this approach, to make your loop work, you would need to change your outer while predicate. Perhaps something like:

```
DECLARE @side1 AS INT = 1;
DECLARE @side2 AS INT = 1;

WHILE (@side1 <= 10) 
    BEGIN
        WHILE @side2 <= 10 
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO dbo.PythagoreanTriangles
                    VALUES (@side1, @side2, SQRT((@side2 * @side2) + (@side1 * @side1)));
                UPDATE dbo.PythagoreanTriangles SET Hypotenuse = ROUND(Hypotenuse, 2)

                SET @side2 = @side2 + 1;
            END;

            SET @side2 = 1;
            SET @side1 = @side1 + 1;
    END;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c5fe/1)**

Comment: Great solution, although it doesn't really help the OP with his `WHILE` loop issue.  I prefer your method better than a loop though by far!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I figured it out!